How can i make so my Next is not set to None in my Flask app?
Im making a Flask app with flask-sqlaclchemy, flask-login and flask-wtf.
My problem is that im trying to set the login system for the first time, i followed the documentation but when trying to use next this is set to None. Thus, making my validation to execute an abort 400. I tried removing the next part and simply goin on without it, but then my app does not store the information for the login, and even tho my login function validates all the data and redirects me to the view i want after login sucessfully, it shows a message that says i dont have the permisions.
This is my code:
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = Blog_User()
        form.populate_obj(user)
        email_db = db.session.execute(db.select(Blog_User).filter_by(email = user.email)).scalar()
        if email_db:
            pass_db = db.session.execute(db.select(Blog_User).filter_by(password = user.password)).scalar()
            if pass_db:
                login_user(user)
                flash("Login Suscessfully!")

                next = request.args.get('next')

                if not url_is_safe(next, request.host):
                    p = url_is_safe(next, request.host)
                    return f"The next is: {next}, and the expresion evaluates to: {p}"


                return redirect(next or url_for("home"))
            else:
                flash("Your password was incorrect, try again.")
                return redirect("/login")
        else:
            flash("You dont have an account.")
            return redirect("/login")
    return render_template("user/login.html", form=form)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Blog_User.query.get(user_id)

here is my structure of the app:
__pycache__
.venv
app
├── __pycache__
├── forms
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── sign_up.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── hash_password.py
│   ├── test_data.py
│   ├── test_post.py
│   ├── test_user.py
│   └── url_has_allowed_h.py
├── models
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── posts.py
│   └── user.py
static
├── img
│   ├── arrow_icon.png
│   └── github-social.png
├── index.css
├── login.css
└── sign_up.css
templates
├── user
│   ├── login.html
│   └── sign_up.html
└── index.html
__init__.py
routes.py
tes.py
instance
├── config.py
└── database_tut.db
.gitignore
config.py
README.md
requirements.txt
run.py

I dont really know why next is required and how it handles the things, only that is kinda the next argument in the iterator or somethig like that.

The URL parameter next is simply a URL to which the user should be directed after completing the login if the user has previously attempted to access a secure area without authentication. Using this parameter is not a requirement for the login to work.
If, as I understand you, the login does not work, this seems to be due to another error in your code. Unfortunately, you have not included the database model, the form and the template, or the initialization of the LoginManager in your question. This means that the error can also occur elsewhere.
However, it is noticeable that the code you have published needs to be optimized and uses a user object for login_user(...) that is not part of the database. This may be the reason why the session is not created correctly and the user cannot be found after redirection.
The following simplified example, on the other hand, uses the user that comes from the database query so that its identifier can be stored within the session and can be found again after redirection.
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        stmt = db.select(Blog_User).filter_by(email = form.email.data)
        user = db.session.execute(stmt).scalar()
        
        # Later, use a hashing algorithm to securely store the password. 
        if user and user.password == form.password.data:
            login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully.')

            next_url = request.args.get('next')
            if next_url and not url_is_safe(next_url, request.host):
                abort(400)

            return redirect(next_url or url_for('home'))

        # For security reasons, do not distinguish between 
        # incorrect username and password.
        flash('Your username or password was incorrect. Try again.')

    return render_template('user/login.html', form=form)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return db.session.get(Blog_User, user_id)

The fact that the URL parameter next is None after a redirect to login may be due to the action attribute being specified within the template. To exclude this, you would have to add the corresponding code to your question.
